# regex needed for parsing string

Tags: regex, vb.net, parsing, delimiter

I am working with government measures and am required to parse a string that contains variable information based on delimiters that come from issuing bodies associated with the [fda](http://www.fda.gov).

I am trying to retrieve the delimiter and the value after the delimiter. I have searched for hours to find a *regex* solution to retrieve both **the delimiter and the value that follows it** and, though there seems to be posts that handle this, the code found in the post haven't worked.

One of the major issues in this task is that the delimiters often have repeated characters. For instance: delimiters are used such as "=", "=,", "/=". In this case I would need to tell the difference between "=" and "=,".

Is there a regex that would handle all of this?

Here is an example of the string :

```
=/A9999XYZ=>100T0479&,1Blah
```

Notice the delimiters are:

```
"=/"
"=>'
"&,1"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By the way I am working with vb.net

Comment: Don't know whether this is what you want or not, but the regex "a(?:b|c)" can match both "ab" and "ac" in the string "ab ac". By the way, what is the desired result of the example given above?

Comment: It is appropriate to show us the code you tried, the result, and why you where not happy with it. Kindly read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this

```
(=/|=>|&,1)|(\w+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/zQ6fG6/1)**

The idea is that the first group contains the delimiters and the 2nd group the content. I assume the content can be word characters (`a` to `z` and digits with underscore). You have then to grab the content of every capturing group.

Comment: Thanks to both of you who answered. I realize that having a delimiter such as "=" and one that is "=>" is tricky as you mentioned. You'd have to do something:find a "=" delimiter and make sure that it isn't followed by ">" to make sure which of the two delimiters you actually found. I did find another article that described testing, using regex, to see if the the text found is "followed' by another text snippet using a "*" character. Is there the opposite?: say a "=" NOT followed by a ">" will look at the two demos. Thanks so much

Comment: @NeilNewton good to know. Btw, did any of the answers solved your question? If so, then you should mark one of them as accepted answer

Comment: This may seem silly to you but the &,1 part of the regex in the first answer doesn't seem to be working; the first answer is the more complete one and more likely to help me. I am not that well versed in regex yet that i can easily make the correction needed to make it work. So I am looking into tutorials to help me. This got me most of the way there but I will need to study the first answer more carefully. If you want me to close this I will and perhaps ask more questions later. Whatever is best for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture both the delimiter and the value as group 1 and 2 respectively.

If your values are all alphanumeric, use this:

```
(&,1|\W+)(\w+)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/534FQ7M3La).

If your values can contain non-alphanumeric characters, it get complicated:

```
(=/|=>|=,|=|&,1)((?:.(?!=/|=>|=,|=|&,1))+.)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/vkPRbfQyG4).

Code the delimiters longest first, eg "=," before "=", otherwise the alternation, which matches left to right, will match "=" and the comma will become part of the value.

This uses a negative look ahead to stop matching past the next delimiter.

Comment: Sorry for the additonal comment. I was trying to find out how I could use a regex to tell the difference between "=" and "=>",  a major problem that I a facing but unfortunately forgot to put in the original post. I apologize.

Comment: I still don't know exactly what you want. The easiest and best way to clarify what you want is to provide several text samples in your question that show all edge cases you want handled. Please edit your question accordingly. I'm sure we can figure this out :)

Comment: Here's the deal. I have looked for regex "recipies" before. In all cases the situations were simple enough that I was able to use the regexes immediately, I can see this works pefectly in the ruby utility, I used it in vb.net using regex split and the  "&,1"  token is not working.

Comment: Here is the code I'm using. I'm not sure if this is an issue of my using vb.net and not ruby. The other tokens seem to work. I am not good enough at regex to figure out what I need to change. I will be looking at tutorials. Here's the code:

Comment: 'Dim r As String = "(=\/|=>|=,|=|&, 1)((?:.(?!=\/|=>|=,|=|&,1))+.)"
            'Dim substrings As String() = Regex.Split(piUDI, r)
            'For Each s As String In substrings
            '    MsgBox(s)
            'Next

Comment: Bohemian, Thanks for offer to help me figure this out. I figure I should either ask for help or close this out. In answer to your question as to what I'm trying to do, I have to parse string with two sets of rather messy delimiters that weren't developed internally. I got good answers but the reality is that I don't know enough about regex to: 1. Figure out why the "&,1" doesn't work in vb.net 2. Understand what the regex strings I've been given mean. I had hoped to do that through tutorials but it's more difficult than I thought in the time I have. Didn't want handholding but, can you help me

Comment: I need just a little guidance in how to interpret this regex:(=/|=>|=,|=|&,1)((?:.(?!=/|=>|=,|=|&,1))+.). Why are the delimiters repeated? I believe the "&,1" might not work.for the posters because they are using a ruby regex tester and I am working in vb. Help!

Comment: @neil the delimiters aren't really repeated. They are there once to match, and again in a negative look ahead so the dot doesn't run past the next delimiter. If `&,1` is causing you headaches, try escaping every character in it in case `&` or comma has special meaning in vb, ie `\&\,\1`, like maybe vb codes back references using `&` where other languages use backslash or `$`